# Bad malloc allocation

Tags: c

I'm working in a project in c ,I want to read word from file and insert them into a multidimensional array ,actually zhen I write few words (150/100) I don't have any problem but when I make a lot of words in this file I have this message :

> ```
> a.out: malloc.c:2385: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
> Aborted (core dumped)
> ```

here is my function:

```
char **tab;
char        *ft_strjoin(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char    *temp;
    size_t  a;
    size_t  b;

    if (s1 == NULL || s2 == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    a = strlen(s1);
    b = strlen(s2);
    temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * (a + b + 1));
    if (temp == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    strcpy(temp, (char*)s1);
    strcat(temp, (char*)s2);
    return (temp);
}

char    **MappingToSet(char *fichier)
{
    char *str;
    int word_len;
    int word_number;
    int fd;
    char *buff;
    int k = 2;
    int n;
    fd = open(fichier,O_RDONLY);
    buff = malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
    tab = (char **)(malloc(sizeof(char*)*1));
    word_len = 0;
    word_number = 0;
    str = strdup("");
    while ((n=read(fd,buff,1)) > 0)
    {
        buff[n] = '\0';
        if (buff[0] != '\n' && buff[0] != '\0')
        {
            str = ft_strjoin(str,buff);
            word_len++;
        }
         if (buff[0] == '\n' )
        {
            str[word_len] = '\0';
            tab[word_number] = malloc(sizeof(char) * word_len);
            strcpy(tab[word_number],str);
            str = strdup(str + word_len);
            word_number++;
            tab = realloc(tab,k * sizeof(char*));
            k++;
            word_len = 0;
        }
    }
    tab[word_number] = malloc(sizeof(char) * word_len);
    strcpy(tab[word_number], str);
    tab = realloc(tab, (k-1) * sizeof(char*));
    tab[word_number + 1] = NULL;
    return (tab);
}
```

Comment: What is `tab`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char) * word_len);` should be `malloc(word_len + 1);`. And fyi, `sizeof(char)` is *always* `1`, so unless you enjoy typing needless code, omit it. That latter case (typing for no reason) may be true, since things like `strcpy(temp, (char*)s1);` where `s1` is already `char*` make no real sense. Casting is no silver bullet, and is far rarer required than you're doing throughout this code anyway.

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't bother people about the reduncancy of `sizeof(char)` -- it's not unreasonable to be consistent in using `sizeof(<type>) * amt` in calls to malloc.

Comment: I know there is a lot of useless thing there I'm juste beginner,it's first time that I hear about leak and I really don't know how to solve that

Comment: Given `str[word_len] = '\0';` what is `str = strdup(str + word_len);` supposed to do?

Comment: str = strdup(str + word_len); juste to make str empty

Comment: somtimes when I put more thane 100000 word in the file it works,but somtimes it doesnt work just with a few number of words and show that message.